# Custom domain on Openshift Nodejs App doesnt show up. [+process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS]

Tags: node.js, git, openshift, ghost-blog

I run a ghost blog on openshift, i created with success custom domains for my site and everything works nice, but the subscribe link as some other links in my menu points to my openshift url `ghost-nodejs.rhcloud.com` than to my custom domain  `my-blog.com`.

After i cloned the git repo on my machine, i opened the `config.js` and changed the `url: 'http://my-ghost-blog.com',` to my custom domain `url: 'http://my-blog.com',` but nothing changes. I also later changed `production: {
        'url: 'http://'+process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS,` to my custom domain but that change made my blog not work at all. ( I completely remove the +process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS part)

Can someone guide me on this?

PS: The git commands i use are `git clone ssh//*****` i alter some stuff locally and then i run 
`git add -A` then `git commit -a -m 'alter my app'` and finally `git push`

Comment: I have same issue with my blog on OpenShift. Do you know, why OpenShift env variable OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS is not set to my custom domain alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you run the following to set your runtime to production

`rhc set-env NODE_ENV=production --app yourappname'

This will make sure that the changes you made under the production section of your config.js are used.

Comment: Thank you @niharvey, sorry for the late acceptance of your answer.